# transitivity of induction

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I want to prove the "transitivity of induction" property: Let $ H\leq K\leq G $ where $ G $ is finite. Let M be an $ FH $-module, where $ F $ is any field. Then $ (M^K)^G\simeq^{FG} M^G $. Would you help me to prove that?

Comment: I know that to prove is not a question, but I want a plot to prove. :)

Comment: The proof will depend on which definition of $M^K$ you are using.

Comment: Suppose that $ G $ is a group and $ H $ is a subgroup of $ G $, $ F $ any field and $ M $ a right $ FH $-module. We define $ M^G = M\otimes_{FH}FG $.

Comment: Then $(M^K)^G = (M \otimes_{FH} FK) \otimes_{FK} FG \cong M \otimes_{FH} (FK \otimes_{FK} FG) \cong M \otimes_{FH} FG = M^G$.